# AngularJS scope return $$state

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive and in this directive I have a value that comes from my controller, here is my directive:

```
angular
  .module('thermofluor')
  .directive('tablePlate', tablePlate)


tablePlate.$inject = ['$timeout', '$q'];

function tablePlate($timeout, $q) {
  var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/crims/thermofluor/experiments/table_plate.html',
    scope: {
      plate: '='
    }
  };

  return directive;

  function link(scope, element) {
    console.log("test");
    var plate = scope.plate;
    console.log(plate);
    scope.letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];
    scope.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

    experiments = [];
    experiments[scope.plate.experiment.well] = [scope.plate.experiment];

    return;
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I `console.log` the scope I see my plate object with everything I need inside, but when I try to `console.log` the `scope.plate` object, the object change and it return me a `$$state`, and I don't know how to use this `$$state`

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: the scope that you are printing is an [AngularJS **Promise**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns). You can resolve it with `scope.plate.then(function(res){ console.log(res) })`

Comment: Is there any other solution more simple ? I'll need to access to my variable so much times

Comment: Promises are asynchronous callbacks, you don't know when the data will arrive: in just a few milliseconds, or in a minute. So you can't really assign the value to a variable (only a Promise). So you have to resolve it every single time. There is a hack, however, where you can assign it to a variable within `angular.config` in your routes (`ngRoute` or `ui.router`) through **resolve** property.

Comment: Is this a good or bad way to put all my code inside the scope.plate.then(function(res){} ? With this method sometimes when I refresh the page is says cannot read property then of undefined, and when I refresh again it works

Comment: keeping everything in `.then` is the way to go. If you have more than one promise to deal with, you need to chain them. (There are some ways you can avoid _Pyramid callback hell_ by stacking `.then().then()`) Also if you have promises that you need to resolve at the same time without chaining, you can use `$q.all()` (it works similarly to `Promise.all()`)

Comment: Okay thanks for all ^^, for the problem of then undefined what can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//use of the controller with scope will resolve your problem

angular
    .module('thermofluor')
    .directive('tablePlate', tablePlate)


tablePlate.$inject = ['$timeout', '$q'];

function tablePlate($timeout, $q) {
    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: ['$scope',function($scope){
                console.log("test");
                var plate = $scope.plate;
                console.log(plate);
                $scope.letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];
                $scope.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

                experiments = [];
                experiments[$scope.plate.experiment.well] = [$scope.plate.experiment];

        }],
        templateUrl: '/crims/thermofluor/experiments/table_plate.html',
        scope: {
            plate: '='
        }
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element) {
        return;
    }
}
```